# Facebook Login Flow for Web without Javascript SDK and Logout

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

The Facebook [Platform Policies section 1.6](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#features) clearly states

> Your website must offer an explicit "Log Out" option that also logs the user out of Facebook.

The [Login Flow for Web without Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/#logout) says on Logging people out

> You can log people out of your app by undoing whatever login status indicator you added, for example deleting the session that indicates a person is logged in. You should also remove the stored access token.

On the other hand [the Login Flow for Web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#logout) says about Logging people out

> Note: This function call will also log the person out of Facebook. The reason for this is that someone may have logged into your app and into Facebook during the login flow. If this is the case, they might not expect to still be logged into Facebook when they log out of your app. To avoid confusing people and to protect personal security, we enforce this logout behavior.

So in my understanding the Login Flow with JS SDK does what the policy says, it logs the user out of Facebook as well. How do I implement the Login Flow *without JS JSDK* correctly, such that i do not violate the Facebook Platform Policy? So far i don't see that the Graph API offers a similar functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be easy, [looking at the PHP SDK’s method getLogoutUrl](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#LC608), that creates an URL of the following scheme:

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=FOO&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

For FOO you just place the URL of your website where you want the user to be redirected to after they are successfully logged out of Facebook (don’t forget to properly URL-encode that value), and USER_ACCESS_TOKEN should be self-explanatory. (You need an active user access token to log the user out of Facebook – obviously, because otherwise *every* site on the web could just redirect me to this address and log me out of Facebook, without me actually wanting that to happen.)